# Insert Dynamic Field data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-data

I am able to get data from my form to backend php but how to insert it to MySQL?

Here is my form

```
<div class="container">
        <form class="form-control" method="post" action="save.php">
            <div id="input_fields">
                <div class="container">
                    <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="name"> <input type="text" name="project[]" placeholder="project"> <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add_field">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#add_field").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();  
                    $("#input_fields").append('<div class="container"><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="name"/> <input type="text" name="project[]" placeholder="project"> <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger">-</button></div>'); 
            });

            $("#input_fields").on("click","#remove", function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
                x--;
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Backend php code Here on foreach I used echo to check data and it show me correct data but it is not inserting to MySQL.

```
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["project"])) { 
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $key => $val) {
        $proj = $_POST['project'][$key];
        echo "Name ".$val." Project ".$proj;
        $insert = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1,colunm2) values ('$val','$proj')";
        $result = $conn->query($insert);
    }

    if($result) {
        echo "Data inserted Successfully";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that there is any error in query. If have then try to fix the following error.

```
if(!$result) die($conn->error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line for now

```
if($result) {
   echo "Data inserted Successfully";
}
```

and define this code inside loop, just below where foreach loop starts -

```
$insert = '';
$result = '';
```

I hope this will help you!